# android check if current view is main layout

Tags: android, layout

I have got a simple Android Application with multiple Layouts and if I press back in a Layout it brings me to Main Menu with this Code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 5
            && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        Log.d("Debug", "onKeyDown Called");
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
}
```

But when I am already in Main Layout I want it to close the Application, but that is my Problem: it won't work, here is a Code I already tried:

```
if(android.R.id.content != R.id.mainLayout){
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
}
```

Can you please tell me how I can check if current view is main layout?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your application is doing. Are you dynamically adding and removing layouts from a main view? Sounds like fragments might simplify your life.

Comment: You can check Id of layout you set as main view.